# Requesting when offline (Cordova-Framework7)

Tags: cordova, request, offline, html-framework-7

I have a project where it is required to implement something that saves the request if the connection was lost somehow, so it can send it as soon as it is back online again. I am not familiar with Cordova/Framework 7 so I would highly appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can handling this by using online and offline event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    var initNetworkCheck = checkConnectionType();
    if(initNetworkCheck.status == Connection.NONE){
        onOffline();
    }

    /*
    * Add offline connection behavier
    */
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

    function onOffline() {
        networkScreenAction();
    }

    /*
    * Add offline connection behavier
    */
    document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

    function onOnline() {
         networkScreenAction();
    }
});

function checkConnectionType() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    var states = {};

    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';// For Browser
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    return {"status": networkState, 'label': states[networkState]};
}

function networkScreenAction()
{
   // Do Somthing
}
```

In this example you can handling online, and offline event..so that you can execute what you want like resend request if not send...

Note: for resend request you can save fail request data/info in localstorage and when you back online you can get it and resend request again...or you can using localforage, or any other method you like.....